# Monopoly millionaire mortgaging of a property to pay for another property

Tags: monopoly-millionaire

Since an agreement could not be made.
And we take monopoly a bit to seriously in this house.
I need a perspective to end this debate.

I landed on boardwalk.  I had 167k in cash to pay for it, but I was 3k shy of having enough cash to complete the (170k) purchase.

Is it legal to mortgage another one of my properties, when the rules state "you must be bankrupt to mortgage properties", to have enough money to pay for the new property? 
This is very serious and I need an outside opinion.

Comment: I just read through the relevant rules a couple times; and I think it's ambiguous/not clear.

Answer (score 5):

I would say no, you are just out of luck.

### Defining Bankruptcy

Since the rules I found [here](http://www.hasbro.com/common/documents/dad288661c4311ddbd0b0800200c9a66/A084A5255056900B108D4B8ADDE8CB0D.pdf) don't explicitly define bankruptcy, but merely list the changes from standard Monopoly rules, I will refer to the [standard rules.](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf) It states

> BANKRUPTCY ... You are declared bankrupt if you owe more than you can
>   pay either to another player or to the Bank.

Since the rules for Millionaire state about mortgage (and other things)

> IMPORTANT: You can ONLY do these things if you’re bankrupt, not under
>   any other circumstances!

Since buying property is optional (the standard rules say that you *may* buy property when you land on it, it is not required), you don't qualify as being bankrupt.  Since you are not bankrupt, mortgaging is not an option.

Answer (score -1):

You must be bankrupt before mortgaging. Since you had 167k and purchasing is optional you can’t mortgage to buy. You could have sold one or your other properties however

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing and referenced answer from over three years ago.